# Establishing bluetooth connection between a J2ME application and a desktop application written with Python (preferably using pybluez)?

Tags: java, python, java-me, bluetooth, jsr82

I am trying to establish a bluetooth connection between my J2ME application (using JSR-082 API) and my desktop application written with Python (using pybluez bluetooth API). However, I could not find a suitable bluetooth communication protocols to pair them.

In pybluez, the way you connect to a server is as follows:

```
addr, port = "01:23:45:67:89:AB", 1
sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((addr, port))
```

However in JSR-082 bluetooth API, the way you create a server is as follows:

```
StreamConnectionNotifier connectionNotifier =
    (StreamConnectionNotifier) Connector.open("btspp://localhost:" + 
    "0000000000000000000000000000ABCD;name=JSR82_ExampleService");
streamConnection = connectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen();
```

or as follows:

```
L2CAPConnectionNotifier connectionNotifier = 
    (L2CAPConnectionNotifier) Connector.open("btl2cap://localhost:" + 
    "0000000000000000000000000000ABCD;name=JSR82_ExampleService");
streamConnection = connectionNotifier.acceptAndOpen();
```

In pybluez API we use port numbers, and in JSR-082 API we use URLs. How am I going to establish a bluetooth connection then? Is there a way to create a server using a port number in JSR-082 API?

Comment: I tried to do the same thing, but I failed. I recommend you to use Java on both mobile phone (JSR 82) and computer (BlueCove JSR 82 implementation: http://bluecove.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Using JSR-82, you create a server based on a UUID.  You need to perform an SDP search to determine the "port" (actually, channel number for RFCOMM or PSM for L2CAP) of the remote service.  So, in pybluez, you'd call `bluetooth.find_service()` (as shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/simple/sdp-browse.py)), examine each of the services returned, and pick the one with a matching UUID ("service-id" in bluez).